# SQL Query to Subtract and Sum in same time

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

I want to subtract two columns, and then I want to compute the total of the subtracted values.

I am using MS Access 2010.

```
 Value1        Value2 
 100           50
 100           80
```

I have applied-

`select value1-value2 as Result from tbl`

it gives the result

```
Result 
50
20
```

But I want

```
Result 
70
```

Any idea?

Comment: Have you tried `SELECT SUM(value1 - value2)`?

Comment: This is not really possible with the information you have provided. You need to be able to identify which rows you want to subtract the numbers from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following:

```
select sum(value1-value2) as Result 
from tbl
```

Comment: I have tried the above statement but not succeed. the problem was with data type.I have taken wrong data type..

Comment: If value1-value2 was giving you the mentioned results, then sum(value1-value2) should work also!

Comment: Now here an another problem. when i use above statement it works. but when add few more fields then does not work. For eg- select name,customerid,sum(value1-value2) as Result 
from tbl...Now what to do?

Comment: Please create another question to elaborate your issue.

Comment: for that you need to use group by clause with the remaining columns.

Answer (score 0):

Use this statement:

```
SELECT SUM(Value1- value2) as Result
FROM tbl
```

Answer (score 0):

```
--CREATE TABLE #COUNT (VAL1 INT ,VAL2 INT)
--INSERT INTO #COUNT VALUES (100,50)
--INSERT INTO #COUNT VALUES (100,80)


CREATE TABLE #COUNT1 (VAL1 INT )
INSERT INTO #COUNT1 SELECT VAL1-VAL2  FROM #COUNT

SELECT  VAL1 AS RESULT  FROM #COUNT1
COMPUTE SUM(VAL1) 

DROP TABLE #COUNT1
```